# Modifying contents of data section in ELF

Tags: linux, executable, elf

I have a program that initializes an array to 0. I have pointed the value of that array to a custom section using: `__attribute__((section(".mysection")))`

```
struct my_struct my_array[1] __attribute__((section(".mysection"))) = {
    {0, 0},
};
```

The above is only so that we have a default and the linker marks the section as loadable and also includes it in the appropriate section list.

Now I wish to edit the generated ELF and modify the contents of that struct as I choose. I already have a binary file which contains the contents that I wish to have for that section.
I tried using --remove-section and --add-section but could not force the new section to be part of the sections.

Not sure if --update-section would help here, but the microcontroller I have doesn't have --update-section in objcopy and when I try the public version of it, that says that it doesnt support the bfd target.

FWIW, the ELF doesnt use any relocatable addresses etc. All addresses are physical addresses in memory.

Is there a way to achieve this? I just need to replace the contents of the section and modify its length.

Comment: “And modify its length” — if the section in your original ELF doesn’t already have the right length then that is going to be a lot more complicated. Just replacing the data if the section is already the right length should be possible assuming that you are just wanting to binary edit the ELF file.

Comment: A common way to fill an array with precomputed data, instead of messing around with sections in the object file, is just to generate a simple C source file defining an initialized array.  E.g. have a script that outputs `struct my_struct my_array[1] = { ` followed by all the desired entries in decimal or hex.  And then just compile it and link it with your program.  Leave the object file handling to existing tools that know how to handle it.

Comment: For now I made the array size bigger so compiler initializes the space to all 0's and then wrote a script to modify it after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

In case other, more simple ways, are not suitable, you may implement such functionality by using [ELFIO](http://elfio.sourceforge.net/) library.

Comment: Will give this a try. For now I made the array size bigger so compiler initializes the space to all 0's and I dont have to worry about the size. I wrote a script to edit the 0's in the elf with the bytes I wanted after the fact.